# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'CuDNNLSTM'

Tags: tensorflow

My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# initial layer
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# emmbed word vectors
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(fasttext_model.wv.vocab)+1,300,input_length=X.shape[1],weights=[embed_matrix],trainable=False))


model.add(tf.CuDNNLSTM(300, return_sequences = True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1],activation="softmax")) 
model.summary()
```

I am getting the following error in this code. how can i fix this?

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'CuDNNLSTM'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using versions before 2.0, the statement is:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(300, return_sequences = True))
```

If the version of tensorflow is >= 2.0, this layer has been removed. Instead, simply using LSTM layer with default activations automatically uses CuDNN. You can just use:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(300, return_sequences = True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have a Nvidia card and also already installed CuDNN

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html